# tokio::time::timeout and reqwests, can't wrap my future in a timeout

Tags: rust

Reproducible example [main.rs] [https://pastebin.com/E2SYsCvp]

My original query loop:

```
fn construct_headers() -> HeaderMap {
    let mut headers = HeaderMap::new();
    headers.insert(USER_AGENT, HeaderValue::from_static("xxx-zzz"));
    headers
}

let mut headers = HeaderMap::new(); headers.insert(USER_AGENT, HeaderValue::from_static("reqwest"));
let client = reqwest::Client::builder().build()?;
let params = [("subreddit", subr), ("size", &size.to_string()), ("before", &last.clone())]; //before is shifting timestamps based on last entry's time created in responses to progress back in time

let mut resp = client.get("https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/submission/")
    .query(&params)
    .headers(construct_headers())
    .send()
    .await?
    .text()
    .await?
;

if resp.to_string().contains("Too Many"){
    'rqst:loop{
        thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_secs(1));
        resp = client.get("https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/submission/")
            .query(&params)
            .headers(construct_headers())
            .send()
            .await?
            .text()
            .await?
        ;
        if resp.to_string().contains("Too Many"){
            continue
        } else {
            break 'rqst
        };
    };
};
```

Trying to wrap it in timeout, because it fails occasionally after few hours of polling (infinite timeout) due to the API's problem:

```
if resp.to_string().contains("Too Many"){
    'rqst:loop{
        thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_secs(1));
        resp = client.get("https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/submission/")
            .query(&params)
            .headers(construct_headers())
            // .send()
            // .await
        ;
        match tokio::time::timeout(std::time::Duration::from_secs(30), resp.send()).await {
            Ok(result) => match result {
                Ok(response) => response.text().await?, //convert to text - will this work?
                Err(e) => return Ok(linkz), //early return
            },
            Err(_) => return Ok(linkz), //early return
        };
    if resp.to_string().contains("Too Many"){
        continue
    } else {
        break 'rqst
    };
    };
};
```

No matter how I try to make it happen (whether resp shadowing ends just with `.send()` or `.await` as the commented out lines show) the errors are abundant. Oftentimes tokio expects String, or do I misunderstand it?

Example if ends with `.send()`. Technically this is the future?:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/main.rs:204:24
    |
191 |           let mut resp = client.get("https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/submission/")
    |  ________________________-
192 | |             .query(&params)
193 | |             .headers(construct_headers())
194 | |             .send()
195 | |             .await?
196 | |             .text()
197 | |             .await?
    | |___________________- expected due to this value


204 |                   resp = client.get("https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/submission/")
    |  ________________________^
205 | |                     .query(&params)
206 | |                     .headers(construct_headers())
207 | |                     .send()
    | |___________________________^ expected struct `std::string::String`, found opaque type
    |
   ::: /home/xxx/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/reqwest-0.11.11/src/async_impl/request.rs:499:26
    |
499 |       pub fn send(self) -> impl Future<Output = Result<Response, crate::Error>> {
    |                            ---------------------------------------------------- the found opaque type
    |
    = note:   expected struct `std::string::String`
            found opaque type `impl Future<Output = Result<reqwest::Response, reqwest::Error>>`

error[E0277]: `std::string::String` is not a future
   --> src/main.rs:210:80
    |
210 |                 match tokio::time::timeout(std::time::Duration::from_secs(30), resp).await {
    |                       --------------------                                     ^^^^ `std::string::String` is not a future
    |                       |
    |                       required by a bound introduced by this call
    |
    = help: the trait `Future` is not implemented for `std::string::String`
    = note: std::string::String must be a future or must implement `IntoFuture` to be awaited
note: required by a bound in `timeout`
   --> /home/xxx/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.19.2/src/time/timeout.rs:73:8
    |
73  |     T: Future,
    |        ^^^^^^ required by this bound in `timeout`


error[E0277]: `std::string::String` is not a future
   --> src/main.rs:210:85
    |
210 |                 match tokio::time::timeout(std::time::Duration::from_secs(30), resp).await {
    |                       --------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^ `std::string::String` is not a future
    |                       |
    |                       this call returns `std::string::String`
    |
    = help: the trait `Future` is not implemented for `std::string::String`
    = note: std::string::String must be a future or must implement `IntoFuture` to be awaited
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Future` for `tokio::time::Timeout<std::string::String>`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `IntoFuture` for `tokio::time::Timeout<std::string::String>`
help: remove the `.await`
    |
210 -                 match tokio::time::timeout(std::time::Duration::from_secs(30), resp).await {
210 +                 match tokio::time::timeout(std::time::Duration::from_secs(30), resp) {
    |
```

Example if ends with `.headers()`:

```
204 |                   resp = client.get("https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/submission/")
    |  ________________________^
205 | |                     .query(&params)
206 | |                     .headers(construct_headers())
    | |_________________________________________________^ expected struct `std::string::String`, found struct `reqwest::RequestBuilder`
```

In general the future I want to wrap is just

```
resp = client.get("https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/submission/")
            .query(&params)
            .headers(construct_headers())
            .send()
            .await?
```

However it doesn't work no matter how I put it in the tokio timeout.
I've never used tokio's timeout until now, how do I do this? What's wrong here and why is String expected? This works normally with just `.await`ing the `send()`.

According to the snippet from previous error

```
found opaque type
    |
    = note:   expected struct `std::string::String`
            found opaque type `impl Future<Output = Result<reqwest::Response, reqwest::Error>>`
```

it expects String....Why?

```
pub fn timeout<T>(duration: Duration, future: T) -> Timeout<T>
where
    T: Future,
```

I'm putting a future there.

**EDIT:**

Fixed the issue somewhat by dropping the shadowing idea. But I believe the program will still fail. The problem was that the first `resp`  results in a String, so later it will expect a String.

```
if resp.to_string().contains("Too Many"){
    println!("2many rqstz");
    'rqst:loop{
        thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_secs(1));
        let resp = client.get("https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/submission/")
            .query(&params)
            .headers(construct_headers())
            .send()
        ;
        match tokio::time::timeout(std::time::Duration::from_secs(30), async {&resp}).await {
            Ok(result) => result,
            Err(_) => return Ok(linkz),
        };
    if resp.await?.text().await?.contains("Too Many"){
        println!("2mny");
        continue
    } else {
        break 'rqst
    };
    };
};
```

I am afraid this will get stuck in the loop endlessly again because of
`if resp.await?.text().await?.contains("Too Many"){`

this line. But I will know after hours of it running (the API calls await forever only after long time, at the last ever responses from a subreddit).

If anybody has any tips as to what to do here to make it more safe - it seems to me now the if condition separately awaits the `resp`? So without shadowing, if the `resp` times out the if will stuck itself in the infinite loop which was my initial problem?
However, if the first attempt fails, it should early return. Since it's still messy, please advise.

Comment: Missing `client`, `params`, `construct_headers`. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: updated OP, the `construct_headers` ended up being 'unused', I initially wanted to make it a dynamically shifting headers method but since it was not needed, I left it like this.

Comment: Ideally, a minimal reproducible example would also include a `main()`, so that you can just copy-paste it into a `main.rs` and run it. But I'll accept it this time ;)
Although I have to say I'd prefer to also have the `use` statements somewhere.

Comment: Unknown variables `subr`, `size`, `last`. Ok slowly this is getting annoying. *Please* recreate your code on https://play.rust-lang.org/ until it gives you *exactly* the error message you describe, and then post the code here. This is my current attempt: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d6e1ea490fb3c89f702be130c460e7d5
We can't help you if we can't reproduce your problem. Please actually read [how to write a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and don't just skip over it.

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b6251ead1d9d47dbd2c3c76cb9dce931

Comment: Can't run this in playground due to limitations, is what I've found. However I appreciate greatly the effort.

Comment: You have to click on `Share -> Permalink to the playground`, otherwise it just links me to the original code.
If you can't run it in the playground, then create a new rust project and write the minimal example inside the `main.rs`, and then copy the *entire* `main.rs` here. I'm not trying to be annoying, I actually would like to give your problem a go, but so far it turns out frustrating as I can't reproduce your error message.

Comment: here's main.rs => https://pastebin.com/dqH3dN2h || this piece of code is what needs that timeout addition whilst maintaining shadowing somehow? without it code is messy or quits early or there's multiple futures for one "object" so what I updated in the OP doesn't really work because I can't figure out how to do conditional checks only if there is no timeout.

Comment: Why not paste this in your question? This is now an actual minimal example.

Comment: Cannot reproduce your modified code: Unknown variable `linkz`.

Comment: Also minor nitpick: You don't need to do `resp.to_string()`, `resp` is already a string. `to_string()` just does a pointless copy.

Comment: I need more time on this, I will update later, thank you:)

Comment: Forgot to remove the awaits from `resp` and now it's again not working. Updating OP with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, a couple of things I would improve:

- `resp.to_string()` doesn't do much, because `resp` is already a string. It simply copies it into a new object. Just remove `.to_string()`.
- *Never* use `thread::sleep` in an `async` program. Use `tokio::time::sleep` instead. Otherwise you block the entire event loop.
- Don't just return `Ok(())` in an error case, use proper error handling instead
- You query twice, once outside and once inside the loop. You can combine those two.
- You `timeout` on the `send()`, but not on the `text()`. The `text()` can hang just as much, as it is the actual data transfer. You can move all the entire logic of this in a nested function, to simplify it.

You already figured out that the problem with your change was that `resp` is already a `String`. You cannot assing the result of `.headers()` to it. You can, however, simply create a new variable for that.

That said, I had the liberty to implement the feedback and did some refactoring:

```
use reqwest::{
    header::{HeaderMap, HeaderValue, USER_AGENT},
    Client,
};
use std::time::Duration;

use thiserror::Error;

#[derive(Error, Debug)]
pub enum RedditPollError {
    #[error("poll timed out")]
    PollTimeout,
    #[error("the connection failed")]
    ConnectionFailed(#[from] reqwest::Error),
}

async fn poll_reddit_submissions() -> Result<String, RedditPollError> {
    let subr = "selfie"; //example subreddit
    let last = "1658059417"; //current time
    let size = "100"; //max response size

    fn construct_headers() -> HeaderMap {
        let mut headers = HeaderMap::new();
        headers.insert(USER_AGENT, HeaderValue::from_static("xxx-zzz"));
        headers
    }

    let mut headers = HeaderMap::new();
    headers.insert(USER_AGENT, HeaderValue::from_static("reqwest"));
    let client = reqwest::Client::builder().build()?;
    let params = [
        ("subreddit", subr),
        ("size", &size.to_string()),
        ("before", &last.clone()),
    ]; //before is shifting timestamps based on last entry's time created in responses to progress back in time

    Ok(loop {
        async fn try_poll(client: &Client, params: &[(&str, &str)]) -> reqwest::Result<String> {
            client
                .get("https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/submission/")
                .query(params)
                .headers(construct_headers())
                .send()
                .await?
                .text()
                .await
        }

        let response = tokio::time::timeout(Duration::from_secs(30), try_poll(&client, &params))
            .await
            .map_err(|_| RedditPollError::PollTimeout)?
            .map_err(|e| RedditPollError::ConnectionFailed(e))?;

        if response.contains("Too Many") {
            tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
        } else {
            break response;
        };
    })
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    match poll_reddit_submissions().await {
        Ok(message) => println!("{}", message),
        Err(e) => println!("Failed: {}", e),
    }
}
```

I assume that some of the parameters will probably have to be moved out of `poll_reddit_submissions` and become a function parameter instead.